# Installing VirtualBox breaks TFS Server 2010 services

Tags: virtualbox, windows-server-2008, connection, services

After installing VirtualBox on my server called `MyTFSServer` (Windows Server 2008), the TFS Server services are broken - i.e. cannot connect to `MyTFSServer` from Visual Studio IDE.

I've tried 1) refreshing all related services from `Component Services` of the OS, 2) call `reapplying` from TFS console. Though, that doesn't help.

Do you have the same issue? What is the workaround for that?

Hope to hear from you,

Nam.

Comment: I cannot test it right now... do you have some errors in your eventlogs?

Comment: I know in VMware you can set requests to certain ports on the host to be forwarded to the guest OS, is it possible Virtualbox has done something similar automatically, and requests are being sent to the guest OS instead of TFS? You could check event log etc for errors from TFS saying it cant bind to a port (or similar). Can you still access the web interface to TFS?